# Code control couldn't go inside the child class constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, squish

I have been learning squish to automate a desktop application and I'm using Javascript at language to write my tests.
So I have these three following classes in my code : Actions, Button and AppElements. And AppElement class creates an instance of Button elements which is inheriting Actions class.
import * as names from 'names.js';

```
class Actions{
   
   constructor(appObject){
      this.object=(appObject); 
   }
   
   doubleclick(){
      doubleClick(waitForObjectExists(this.object));
   }
   
}

class Button extends Actions{
   constructor(anElement){
      this.object=anElement;
      super(anElement);
   }
}

class AppElements {       
   get dashboardButton() { return new Button(names.contentButtonDashboardWcPushButton);}
}

export
{
   Actions,
   AppElements,
   Button
};

import * as names from 'names.js';

function main() {
   // attach the desktop application
   let dash= new test.AppElements();

   dash.dashboardButton.doubleclick();
}
```

But when the property dashboardButton() is being called from the test script(from the main function) then it first goes to line  constructor(appObject){ but does not enter in the constructor block and gives following error

error Detail Attempted to access uninitialized this value. Forgot to call super() in derived class?

And because of that the Actions class can never be called and I cannot access any methods of the Actions class.

Would it be great if i could get some help to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) it says...

> When used in a constructor, the super keyword appears alone and must be used before the `this` keyword is used. The super keyword can also be used to call functions on a parent object.

So try:

```
class Button extends Actions {
    constructor(anElement) {
        super(anElement);
        this.object = anElement;
    }
}
```

Related information:

- [JavaScript extensions in Squish 6.6](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/new-javascript-squish-6-6/)
- [Super](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/new-javascript-squish-6-6/#super)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well but that also doesn't work. The code control never even go inside the constructor but it fall over just before reaching inside it at line constructr (){

Comment: It works for me when putting all the code that you provided into a single file and commenting out the "export" statement. So you must be doing something different at your end.

Comment: Are you using squish. Because it works fine for me too with standard JS. Squish just included class concept in last release. And I found that it just doesn't work in squish only. Have you tried in squish?

Comment: Yes, I have used it in Squish (6.6.x). I have put everything into a single file, the standard test case file (test.js). I have commented out the export in your code. I recommend to contact the technical support of the vendor of the tool.